# Numpy: insert a row of 0s for each array in an array of arrays

Tags: numpy

I have a three-dimensional numpy array of size (5000, 8, 9)

I would like to insert a row of 0s as the first row for each of the 5000 arrays, such that the new shape will be (5000, 9, 9) and the first row will be 0s.

How can I do this elegantly in numpy?

EDIT:

Thanks for the inspiration, Ben. I'm trying but I clearly don't have it yet. Here's an MWE of what I have so far:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n1 = np.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]], [[3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2], [5,4,3], [6,5,4]]])
>>> n1
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]],

       [[ 3,  2,  1],
        [ 4,  3,  2],
        [ 5,  4,  3],
        [ 6,  5,  4]]])
>>> proper = np.zeros(((3, 4, 3)))
>>> proper
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
>>> np.insert(proper, n1, axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: insert() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)

>>> np.insert(proper, 0, n1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4435, in insert 
    new[tuple(slobj)] = values
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,4,3) into shape (2)

>>> np.insert(n1, 0, proper)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4435, in insert 
    new[tuple(slobj)] = values
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,4,3) into shape (3)
```

Comment: The elegant solution to any problem is to try solving it. You could insert your array at the correct location into an array of zeros of the proper shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the follwing:
Let n1 be any tensor as per your required shape:

```
n1 = np.empty(shape=(5000, 8, 9))
print(n1.shape)
```

We add a vector at the 0th index, and setting the required axis

```
n2 = np.insert(n1, 0, np.ones(shape=(1,)), axis=1)
print(n2.shape)
```

You can verify with

```
print(n2[0][0])
print(n2[1][0])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it to insert zeros instead of ones, but otherwise perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array filled with zeros and insert your original array into it using indexing:

```
a = np.arange(5000*8*9).reshape(5000,8,9)
b = np.zeros((5000,9,9))
b[:,1:,:] = a
b[0]
>>> array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
           [ 9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17.],
           [18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26.],
           [27., 28., 29., 30., 31., 32., 33., 34., 35.],
           [36., 37., 38., 39., 40., 41., 42., 43., 44.],
           [45., 46., 47., 48., 49., 50., 51., 52., 53.],
           [54., 55., 56., 57., 58., 59., 60., 61., 62.],
           [63., 64., 65., 66., 67., 68., 69., 70., 71.]])
```